# Sabayon - mysql (and other services) won't start

Tags: gentoo, init-script, init, sabayon, openrc

It's a fresh install of Sabayon Linux. I installed mysql (equo install dev-db/mysql), configured it (emerge --config ...), but it doesn't start using /etc/init.d script:

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql start
 * WARNING: mysql is already starting
# /etc/init.d/mysql status
 * You are attempting to run an openrc service on a
 * system which openrc did not boot.
 * You may be inside a chroot or you may have used
 * another initialization system to boot this system.
 * In this situation, you will get unpredictable results!
 * If you really want to do this, issue the following command:
 * touch /run/openrc/softlevel
# /etc/init.d/mysql stop
 * ERROR: mysql stopped by something else
```

Touching /run/openrc/softlevel causes even more errors. Googling doesn't advise much.

I remember recent OpenRC migration on my Gentoo box, but there I'm still using init.d scripts. Anything else changed I didn't notice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of services run by process manager such as : `upstart`, `systemd`, `OpenRC` (your case) , `SysV` and so on. if get `ps ax |ergep -i mysql` you'll find out myql is running,

Use the following documentation: [OpenRC doc](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/openrc-migration.xml)

Comment: Uh... yes, it's there... now. I promise, I checked several times, attempting to connect via MySQL workbench and also by checking processes with ps and it was NOT running. I guess it was all about asking a question at Stack Exchange which forced it to run eventually. Magic, yes.

Answer (score 0):

OpenRC heavily relies on state files to track the expected status of a service.

It is not being especially smart about it.

This means if *any* given piece of information is wrong (i.e. a chroot that didn't play through an openrc shutdown correctly before a start up), it will be pretty stuck.

a **start-stop-start sequence** should always recover from such a situation, then you just need to make sure you have the order right.

unfortunately there is no law requiring init authors to read up on state machines.